# Не получается отдать view браузеру

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

***Есть всего один класс `Application`:***

```
@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String showHelloWorld() {
        return "hello-world";
    }

}
```

***Структура проекда выглядит следующим образом:***
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Зависимости:***

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-strater-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-strater-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

***Проблема:***

При запуске приложения и переходу по урлу `http://localhost:8080/hello` возникает ошибка:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
```

При этом если я зайду по урлу `http://localhost:8080/readme.txt`, то текст из соответствующего файла будет изображен в бразуере.

Что я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в зависимостях `artifactId` прописан с ошибкой: `strater` вместо `starter`. И `spring-boot-starter-web` два раза - один с ошибкой, а другой без. Это не должно собираться - **maven** должен говорить о ненайденных зависимостях.
Вот так будет правильно

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
</dependency>
```